# Python dictionary setdefault() method used as a return value of a recursive function

Tags: dictionary, recursion, setdefault

Say you want to get the nth Fibonacci Number. Then, one possibility is to use the recursive function

```
def Fib(n, d):
    """Assumes n is an int >= 0, d dictionary
    Returns nth Fibonacci number"""
    if n in d:
        return d[n]
    else:
        d[n] = Fib(n-1, d) + Fib(n-2, d)
        return d[n]
```

This works quite well. I tried to shorten this to

```
 def Fib(n, d):
        return d.setdefault(n, Fib(n-1, d) + Fib(n-2, d))
```

But when I can call it with

```
d={0:1, 1:1}
print(f(2, d))
```

, or even with f(1,d), it goes into infinite loop, and restarts the kernel. In fact, any function of this form, say

```
def f(n, d):
    return d.setdefault(n, f(n-1,d))
```

has the same problem. When I tried to debug this, I saw that n keeps decreasing pass the value 1. I guess I don't understand the implementation of this method. I presumed that the setdefault method first checks whether the key is in the dictionary and returns the value, and if not, then assigns the default value to the key and returns the default value. What am I missing here?(I am using Python 3.9.1 with Spyder 4.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

You still need a base case otherwise there's nothing to stop it from calculating, `fib(-1)`, `fib(-2)`, `fib(-99)`, ...

```py
def fib(n, d):
  return n if n < 2 else d.setdefault(n, fib(n-1, d) + fib(n-2, d))

print(fib(10, {0:0, 1:1}))
```

```py
55
```

The problem you are experiencing with `setdefault` is that python is an applicative order language. That means a functions arguments are evaluated *before* a the function is called. In the case of `setdefault`, we will evaluate `fib(n-1,d) + fib(n-2,d)` *before* we attempt to lookup `n` in `d`.

A better interface might be `dict.setdefault(key, lambda: somevalue)` where the lambda is executed *only* if the default needs to be set. We could write this as `lazydefault` below -

```py
def lazydefault(d, key, lazyvalue):
  if key not in d:
    d[key] = lazyvalue()
  return d[key]

def fib(n, d):
  return lazydefault(d, n, lambda: fib(n-1, d) + fib(n-2, d))

print(fib(10, {0:0, 1:1}))
```

```py
55
```

Comment: Thanks, I see! I was trying to return `dict.setdefault(d, n, f(n-1, d))`, and Python was trying to evaluate the input first to be able to call the function. So, gotta stick to your suggestion `return 1 if n < 2 else d.setdefault(n, fib(n-1, d) + fib(n-2, d))`. Thanks!.